# Control Chart behaving Weird

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a control chart in excel. It is very simple chart. But this is acting very weird.

[image: two muppets]

Can anyone tell me, why the max and min lines are not straight and the values are not correct as the table?

Answer (score 0):

Only explanation is that you have accidentally used a "stacked" type of plot instead of a regular one.  Try right clicking the chart and "Change Chart Type" to a "Line" type (one left of the "Stacked Line" type I believe you have on).

Comment: this is a line type chart.

Comment: It is behaving exactly like a stacked line chart.  That is: the value of one data set is added to the one that came before it.  Blue = Quantity on Hand; Red = Blue + Min; Green = Red + Max.